# checking if my person is back to [0,0] given a map in list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task where I have a list of chars that are like a map. My person starts at [0,0] and can go in such direction ['up', 'down', 'left', 'right']. This list is a map [20, 'right', 20, 'right', 20, 'right', 20] so it means the person takes 20 steps up then 20 steps right, 20 steps right, 20 steps right, which means he is back to [0,0]. I'm trying to make a code which will ascertain whether or not he is back to [0,0] in which case it returns True or False if not.

I have created this, but it doesn't work.

```
initial_coordinates = [0, 0]

for step in range(len(list_of_steps)):
    for step_next in range(step+1, len(list_of_steps)):
        if list_of_steps[step].isalnum():
            if list_of_steps[step] is 'Left':
                array[0] += -int(list_of_steps[step_next])
            if list_of_steps[step] is 'Right':
                array[0] += int(list_of_steps[step_next])
            if list_of_steps[step] is 'Down':
                array[1] += -int(list_of_steps[step])
        if list_of_steps[step].isdigit():
            array[1] += int(list_of_steps[step])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 2 things, a direction and a turn. If your **direction** is to the right, then the X value should be increased. but if you **turn** to the right, then it depends what your initial direction was. For example if you start with going up, then go right twice, you are actually going down. Hope this makes sense.

I created an example with which you could actually move a person in certain directions, based on instructions of an array. Hope this will be useful for you :)

```
from enum import Enum, auto


class Direction(Enum):
    UP = auto()
    RIGHT = auto()
    DOWN = auto()
    LEFT = auto()


class Person:
    coordinates = [0, 0]
    currentDirection = Direction.UP

    def step(self, number_of_steps: int):
        if self.currentDirection == Direction.RIGHT:
            self.coordinates[0] += number_of_steps
        elif self.currentDirection == Direction.LEFT:
            self.coordinates[0] -= number_of_steps
        elif self.currentDirection == Direction.UP:
            self.coordinates[1] += number_of_steps
        elif self.currentDirection == Direction.DOWN:
            self.coordinates[1] -= number_of_steps


if __name__ == "__main__":
    person = Person()
    list_of_steps = [20, Direction.RIGHT, 20, Direction.DOWN, 20, Direction.LEFT, 20]

    for instruction in list_of_steps:
        if isinstance(instruction, Direction):
            person.currentDirection = instruction
        elif isinstance(instruction, int):
            person.step(instruction)

    print(person.coordinates)
```